# Не работает вставка результатов поиска в инпут

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Нужно , чтоб при наборе символов в инпут , выбивало результаты поиска по json массиву, в этот самый инпут. Для этого я использовал библиотеку "ui.autocomplete".
Но что, то не работает , не могу понять причину. Кто  уже работал с этой библиотекой подскажите, что не так.

Ниже представляю свой скрипт для илюстрации проблемы:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput">
$(function() {
    var projects =  [ {
    "data": {
        "allfilms": {
            "rosdestvenskaya istoriya": {},
            "sreck": {},
            "lednikoviy period": {},
            "simsoni": {},
            "sauth parck": {},
            "rapuncel": {}
        }
    }
}

$( "#myinput" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#myinput" ).val( ui.item.data.allBrand);
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#myinput" ).val( ui.item.data.allBrand );


        return false;
    }
})
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.data.allBrand + "<br>" + item.data.allBrand + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Вот версия с подключенной библиотекой : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/35/

Comment: У вас массив с данными обёрнут в конструкцию DOM-Ready, что совсем не обязательно, а вот сам код, который должен работать после загрузки DOM - нет. [пример в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/40/)

Comment: `"sreck": {},` Okay

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не работает вставка результатов поиска в инпут?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446435/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82)