# Почему не работает вставка результатов поиска в инпут?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Нужно, чтобы при наборе символов в инпут, выбивало результаты поиска по json массиву, в этот самый инпут. Для этого я использовал библиотеку "ui.autocomplete". Но что-то не работает, не могу понять причину. Кто уже работал с этой библиотекой подскажите, что не так.

Ниже представляю свой скрипт для иллюстрации проблемы:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput">

$("#myinput").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $("#myinput").val(ui.item.data.allBrand);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#myinput").val(ui.item.data.allBrand);
            $("#myinput-id").val(ui.item.data.allBrand);
            $("#myinput-description").html(ui.item.data.allBrand);
            $("#myinput-icon").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
})
```

Вот версия с подключенной библиотекой : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/39/

Comment: Пользуйтесь редактором с подсветкой синтаксиса. Они сильно помогают видеть проблемы со скобками. Также можно использовать утилиты автоматического форматирования кода или сервисы, например для JavaScript: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причины довольно просты.

1. Вы уже второй раз неправильно делаете описание своего projects объекта для автозаполнения. Расставьте нормально скобки и убедитесь, что он находится в нужной области видимости.
2. В зависимости от версии надо использовать не `.data( "autocomplete" )`, а `.data( "ui-autocomplete" )`.

Для примера:

`<input id="myinput" type="text">`

```
$(function(){
    var projects =  [
        { name: "rosdestvenskaya istoriya"},
        { name: "sreck"},
        { name: "lednikoviy period"},
        { name: "simsoni"},
        { name: "sauth parck"},
        { name: "rapuncel"}
    ];
//*************************************************************************
    $("#myinput").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#myinput" ).val( ui.item.name );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#myinput" ).val(  ui.item.name );
            return false;
        }
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.name + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```